# Get all files from gitlab snippets using curl

Tags: curl, gitlab, code-snippets

Is there a way to get all files embedded in gitlab snippets using curl command?

Using the following command I only get the first file.

```sh
curl -O "https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2264390/raw"
```

Since the snippet gathers 3 files I would like to download them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the snippets API to get the list of all the files and URLs.

https://gitlab.com/api/v4/snippets/2264390

```
SNIPPET_ID=2264390
curl "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/snippets/$SNIPPET_ID" | jq -r .files[].raw_url
```

```
https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2264390/raw/main/grafana.service
https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2264390/raw/main/install-grafana-loki-promtail.sh
https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2264390/raw/main/loki-config.yaml
https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2264390/raw/main/loki.service
https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2264390/raw/main/promtail-config.yaml
https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2264390/raw/main/promtail.service
```

You could pipe that output to `xargs` and curl them as well, if you wanted.

If you were open to using something other than `curl` snippets work mostly like any other repository and can be cloned with HTTPS/SSH.

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/snippets/2264390
```